# Use template to construct md5 hash algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, hash, md5

So this might be a weird one:

```
hashlib.md5((hashlib.md5(salt).hexdigest())+(hashlib.md5(plaintext).hexdigest())).hexdigest()
```

That's MyBB's hashing algorithm. In my python program, that's easy to implement. However, when the hashing algorithm isn't known, and the user is required to enter one, I have no idea how to implement that.

So basically I want to hash something with an algorithm that the user enters. If their algorithm is:

```
md5(salt + md5(password))
```

I want to do:

```
hashlib.md5(salt + hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest()).hexdigest()
```

Help?

Oh, and any modules used must be native: pre-included in Python 2.

Comment: I'd be very careful with `exec`, even for the client-side applications. For example, if the script runs with high privileges, it can be used for escalation (exec("__import__('subprocess').call(['rm', '-rf', '/'])")). I'm not sure if that's relevant for your case, just I'm a bit paranoic about those kinds of assumptions about the context where the program is expected to run.

Comment: You've probably already heard this, but md5 is no longer a good choice for hashing passwords.  If you're just wanting a checksum or something that's probably fine, but for security it's no longer considered secure.  You seem to be doing password encryption here, not checksums, so I would consider using sha256 or something more modern.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html shows the docs on what's built in to python.  You can look at hashlib.algorithms to see what algorithms are built-in.  My python instance shows sha512 as the most modern one available by default.

Comment: @rossdavidh I'm working on a hashcracker so the security, or lack thereof, of the algorithm isn't really my concern. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) as a parser, for example:

```
import hashlib
from jinja2.sandbox import SandboxedEnvironment

def md5(s):
    return hashlib.md5(s).hexdigest()

# Sandbox because the source is likely to be untrusted
env = SandboxedEnvironment()

# Parsing any formula, wrapped in {{ ... }}
template = env.from_string('{{md5(salt + md5(password))}}')

# Running it:
hash_ = template.render(md5=md5, salt='3Fd0@5l4x', password='secret')
# hash_ == u'10aaeb818dd269d75bf460469c6b90ab'
```

As @nathancahill correctly suggests, you could improve this further to include more algorithms:

```
import functools

def hexify(algorithm):
    func = getattr(hashlib, algorithm)
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def hex_func(s):
        return func(s).hexdigest()

    return hex_func

algorithms = dict((name, hexify(name)) for name in hashlib.algorithms)

template.render(salt='3Fd0@5l4x', password='secret', **algorithms)
```

Comment: You could go a step farther and inject all `hashlib.algorithms`

Comment: What are the risks of running it outside of the sandboxed env? I mean, it's a python program that runs client side.

Comment: @Aurora if it's a client-side program, then probably none, at least I cannot come up with anything on top of my head.

Comment: Okay. @bereal could you explain the last line?

Comment: @Aurora you mean, the last line with `template.render()`? It is when the previously compiled template will produce the output. The keyword arguments `salt`, `password` and algorithm functions will be used as the template variables, just as in normal Python code (in fact, Jinja generates Python code for templates internally, but that should not bother a regular library user).

Comment: Hmm, I'll look into that. I just feel really uncomfortable putting something into one of my programs without understanding how it works. I'll do some research and them maybe add it. Oh, and I've added a possible solution to the OP. Opinions? @bereal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71448/discussion-between-aurora-and-bereal).

Comment: Why is template = env.from_string('{{md5(salt + md5(password))}}') repeated twice? @bereal

Comment: @Aurora my bad, sorry. Fixed.

Comment: Also, 'salt' is repeated twice here: template.render(salt=salt='3Fd0@5l4x', password='secret', **algorithms) @bereal

Comment: @bereal I have implemented your excellent solution into my code, but I have a problem. The imported module is not pre-included in Python. Is there a way to do the same thing with native modules?

Comment: @Aurora unfortunately, cannot think of anything decent. Another way would be parsing the expression with [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html), and then evaluating the syntax tree manually. [`asteval`](http://newville.github.io/asteval/) does something similar, but a custom implementation may be a bit painful.